cannot grab gizmo (super noob)
I am following the doughnut tutorial and only got to 6:54 into it.
I select try to move the light source, I have the move tool selected (see screengrab). But it only drags and brings up this square selector box (see screen grab). When I select and move any other object the gizmo is grabbable and works as described it is only the light source that does not work as it is described in the tutorial I am following.
screengrab:

tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0J27sf9N1Y&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEPv5y--4MKpciLaoQYZB1Z

You linked a tutorial, but Andrew is doing everything right in it regarding moving with gizmos and everything works in it, so how is anyone supposed to know what you are doing wrong just from seeing how it's done right?.. This question cannot be answered without you showing what you do instead. I would recommend you just start the tutorial over until you manage to follow it precisely.

The fact that you're seeing a "selector square" when you click and drag means that you're actually clicking on a space away from one of the arrows rather than directly over one of them. Try scrolling a bit closer with the mouse wheel, moving the cursor directly over one of the arrows and then clicking and dragging it.

hello maybe show a screenshot

sorry for being moody and vague I was frustrated.. I have tried to explain more and included a screen grab.. thank you for your time

@JohnEason it looks like he’s right over the arrow to me. This might be a bug, especially since he mentioned he can move other objects just fine.

@TheLabCat Possibly, but you can box-drag up and left as well as down and right to create the selection box so who knows! :^)

I am grabbing right over the arrow of the gizmo, I have tried many times, I have restarted the tutorial twice, there is not much I can do wrong. It is very early in the tutorial. How can only my version of blender have such an obvious bug? :( I do not see what I can be doing wrong though.  As I say it is super early and not much could go wrong.

It's really weird that only one object causes issues with this. If it was all of them, I would suspect an installation or drivers issue, but here it doesn't sound logical if you did only what the tutorial does. If you delete Suzanne and add another one, do you still have that issue? It might be useful to share your file as well.

I cannot reproduce the issue. Anything unusual about your PC? You are using Windows PC with a regular mouse with up to date GPU drivers, right? Have you tried deleting the light and adding a new one instead?

I started a new project and still the issue persists.. I deleted the light and added a new one and still it persists.. I really wanted to learn blender and I am the only person in the world with this issue :(

hi there is nothing unusual about my laptop its a lenovo x380 yoga, I will double check but all the drivers are up to date, I downloaded the lenovo tool to make sure that the drivers are right... its a real head scratcher just my luck :( I really wanted to learn this for work...

to update this I realised there was a newer version of blender so I did a clean reinstall, and the problem is still there so I reported it

This I a known bug with intel igpu which is huge as nearly every laptop has one. I'm now stuck as I cannot learn blender. so any ideas would be amazing. I could try and buy a different laptop with AMD GPU but need it to have a stylus and touch screen. Otherwise maybe a desktop with some kinda screen that can act as a drawing tablet.

I reported it and it's a known bug thats been present for two years. Kinda annoying as igpu is the most common, wish I knew before I got this laptop I got it specifically for animation
